# Is it possible delete entire table stored in S3 buckets from athena query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I want a table to store the history of a object for a week and then replace the same with history of next week. What would be the best way to achieve this in aws?

The data is stored in json format in s3 is a weekly dump. The pipeline runs the script weekly once and dumps data into s3 for analysis.  For the next run of the script i do not need the previous week-1 data, so this needs to be replaced with new week-2 data. The schema of the table remains constant but the data keeps changing every week.

Comment: How is the data stored on S3? Is it uploaded as one big weekly dump, or incrementally? Do you control the upload? What is the naming convention (ie, do you have a date-based partitioning scheme)? Do you need to preserve the data in any form (ie, do you just want it to disappear from Athena, or can you delete entirely)? Do you want a rolling delete, or does it need to be specific to a week's boundary?

Comment: Update your post with the answers to these questions -- _do not just reply in comments_.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use **data partitioning** to solve your issue without deleting underlying S3 files from previous weeks (which is not possible via an Athena query).

Thus, the idea is to use a partition key based on the date, and then use this partition key in the WHERE clause of your Athena request, which will cause Athena to ignore previous files (which are not under the last partition).

For example, if you use the file dump date as partition key (let's say we chose to name it dump_key), your files will have to be stored in subfolders like

```
s3://your-bucket/subfolder/dump_key=2021-01-01-13-00/files.csv
s3://your-bucket/subfolder/dump_key=2021-01-07-13-00/files.csv
```

Then, during your data processing, you'll first need to create your table and specify a partition key with the PARTITIONED BY option.

Then, you'll have to make sure you added a new partition using the PARTITION ADD command every time it's necessary for your use case:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD PARTITION (dump_key='2021-01-07-13-00') location 's3://your-bucket/subfolder/dump_key=2021-01-07-13-00/'
```

Then you'll be able to query your table by filtering previous data using the right WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE dump_key >= 2021-01-05-00-00
```

This will cause Athena to ignore files in previous partitions when querying your table.

Documentation here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html